# Python's argv and bash?

Tags: python, bash, argv

I've been learning and clearing up some misunderstandings with pythons `sys.argv`.  When I was passing different characters from the command-line in bash I noticed:

```
script.py

import sys
def test(x):
    return x

print test(sys.argv)

>>>python script.py [first, second, third]
```

Will print:

```
['script.py', '[first,', 'second,', 'third]']
```

and

```
>>>python script.py {first, second, third}

['script.py', '{first,','second,','third}']
```

But:

```
>>>python script.py (first,second,third)

bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Is this python or bash, maybe both?  Any reason for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's bash; parens run a command chain in a subshell.

```
pwd ; ( cd /tmp ; pwd ) ; pwd
```

You will need to quote the parens if you want to use them in an argument.

```
echo '(foo)'
```

Answer (score 2):

It's the `bash` shell as the error message shows:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

`bash` uses parenthesis for its own purposes (to group commands)

Try escaping the parenthesis like this:

```
   python script.py "(first,second,third)"
```

this may also work:

```
  python script.py \(first,second,third\)
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Ignacio said, try quote every param in bash command line.

However, you seems treat bash as the Python way. They are different things.

Here are a good (and basic) shell scripting tutorial here: http://www.freeos.com/guides/lsst/

You only need to read Chapter 2 to know the answer of your question.

Comment: thanks for the link! I've done some shell scripting but, could learn a lot more :)

Comment: could you point to the page in chapter 2 that mentions this?  I read through it and I didn't see anything mentioning it.

Comment: There are two sections related [command line processing](http://www.freeos.com/guides/lsst/ch02sec13.html) and [more about quotes](http://www.freeos.com/guides/lsst/ch02sec08.html)

Comment: ah, I had been aware of escape quotes, I thought there was going to be something on the parenthesis usage.  Thanks for responding again!